# Abaqus 6.14-2 vumat vexternaldb error code 1073741819 with allocatable arrays

Tags: arrays, subroutine, abaqus

as stated above i am trying to get a vumat running, using allocatable arrays. I need to store and reuse the history of some values, therefore I tried allocatable arrays:

```
C       
  subroutine vumat(
C Read only -
     1   nblock, ndir, nshr, nstatev, nfieldv, nprops, lanneal,
     2   stepTime, totalTime, dt, cmname, coordMp, charLength,
     3   props, density, strainInc, relSpinInc,
     4   tempOld, stretchOld, defgradOld, fieldOld,
     5   stressOld, stateOld, enerInternOld, enerInelasOld,
     6   tempNew, stretchNew, defgradNew, fieldNew,
C Write only -
     7  stressNew, stateNew, enerInternNew, enerInelasNew )
C

    include 'vaba_param.inc'
#include <SMAAspUserSubroutines.hdr>


    dimension props(nprops), density(nblock), coordMp(nblock,*),
    1  charLength(nblock), strainInc(nblock,ndir+nshr),
    2  relSpinInc(nblock,nshr), tempOld(nblock),
    3  stretchOld(nblock,ndir+nshr),
    4  defgradOld(nblock,ndir+nshr+nshr),
    5  fieldOld(nblock,nfieldv), stressOld(nblock,ndir+nshr),
    6  stateOld(nblock,nstatev), enerInternOld(nblock),
    7  enerInelasOld(nblock), tempNew(nblock),
    8  stretchNew(nblock,ndir+nshr),
    8  defgradNew(nblock,ndir+nshr+nshr),
    9  fieldNew(nblock,nfieldv),
    1  stressNew(nblock,ndir+nshr), stateNew(nblock,nstatev),
    2  enerInternNew(nblock), enerInelasNew(nblock)



c    ID & Contents of lStatusArray
      parameter ( j_iID_lStatusArray    = 1)
      parameter ( i_lStatusArray_Status = 1)
      parameter ( n_lStatusArray_size   = 1)
      integer lStatusArray(n_lStatusArray_size)
      pointer(ptrlStatusArray,lStatusArray)

      print *,"huhu"
   c************* this line causes the only error! ***************** 
      ptrlStatusArray = SMALocalIntArrayAccess(j_iID_lStatusArray)

      return
      end
C
C
C ************************************************
C user routine to dynamically exchange data
  Subroutine vexternaldb(lOp, i_Array, niArray, r_Array, nrArray)
*
  include 'vaba_param.inc'
#include <SMAAspUserSubroutines.hdr>

  dimension i_Array(niArray), 
 *   r_Array(nrArray)

C     possible values for argument lOp
  parameter (j_int_startAnalysis   = 0,
 *           j_int_startStep       = 1,
 *           j_int_setupIncrement  = 2,
 *           j_int_startIncrement  = 3,
 *           j_int_endIncrement    = 4,
 *           j_int_endStep         = 5,
 *           j_int_endAnalysis     = 6)

C     contents of i_Array
  parameter (
 *           i_int_nTotalNodes        = 1,
 *           i_int_nTotalElements     = 2,
 *           i_int_kStep              = 3,
 *           i_int_kInc               = 4,
 *           i_int_iStatus            = 5,
 *           i_int_lWriteRestart      = 6)

C     possible values for i_Array(i_int_iStatus) 
  parameter (j_int_continue          = 0,
 *           j_int_terminateStep     = 1,
 *           j_int_terminateAnalysis = 2)

C     contents of r_Array
  parameter (
 *           i_flt_totalTime  = 1,
 *           i_flt_stepTime   = 2,
 *           i_flt_dTime      = 3 )

c    ID & Contents of lStatusArray
  parameter ( j_iID_lStatusArray    = 1)
  parameter ( i_lStatusArray_Status = 1)
  parameter ( n_lStatusArray_size   = 1)
  integer lStatusArray(n_lStatusArray_size)
  pointer(ptrlStatusArray,lStatusArray)

*      
  if( lOp .eq. j_int_StartAnalysis) then

     ptrlStatusArray = SMALocalIntArrayCreate(
 *                     j_iID_lStatusArray, n_lStatusArray_size) 
     lStatusArray(i_lStatusArray_Status) = j_int_continue

  end if 

  if( i_Array(i_int_iStatus) .eq. j_int_TerminateAnalysis .or.
 *    lOp .eq. j_int_endAnalysis) then
     call SMALocalIntArrayDelete(j_iID_lStatusArray)
  end if 
*
*     Skip writing restart frames to save on disk!
  i_Array(i_int_lWriteRestart) = 0
*
  return
  end

C ************************************************
C
```

When I want to run the code, it works well without the marked line. Otherwise, if I want to get access to the array utilizing SMALocalIntArrayAccess, Abaqus crashes:

```
Abaqus JOB test
Abaqus 6.14-2
Begin Compiling Single Precision Abaqus/Explicit User Subroutines
12/8/2016 4:29:41 PM
Intel(R) Visual Fortran Intel(R) 64 Compiler for applications running on Intel(R) 64, Version 17.0 Build 20160721
Copyright (C) 1985-2016 Intel Corporation.  All rights reserved.

End Compiling Single Precision Abaqus/Explicit User Subroutines
Begin Linking Single Precision Abaqus/Explicit User Subroutines
Bibliothek "explicitU.lib" und Objekt "explicitU.exp" werden erstellt.
End Linking Single Precision Abaqus/Explicit User Subroutines
12/8/2016 4:29:41 PM
Begin Analysis Input File Processor
12/8/2016 4:29:41 PM
Run pre.exe
12/8/2016 4:29:42 PM
End Analysis Input File Processor
Begin Abaqus/Explicit Packager
12/8/2016 4:29:42 PM
Run package.exe
 huhu
12/8/2016 4:29:42 PM
Abaqus Error: The executable package.exe
aborted with system error code 1073741819.
Please check the .dat, .msg, and .sta files for error messages if the     files
exist.  If there are no error messages and you cannot resolve the     problem,
please run the command "abaqus job=support information=support" to     report and
save your system information.  Use the same command to run Abaqus that you
used when the problem occurred.  Please contact your local Abaqus support
office and send them the input file, the file support.log which you just
created, the executable name, and the error code.
Abaqus/Analysis exited with errors
```

I have totally no idea what I can do now. I tried several machines aswell.

Comment: I do not have experience with 6.14/SMAAspUserSubroutines, so I can't answer the specific question, but in the past I've successfully used allocatable arrays with my Abaqus subroutines. Have you tried allocating without SMAAspUserSubroutines?

Comment: I think you are accessing the array before it is created. Try to test it first if it exists and only then read it